# How to reconstruct multiple variables into one with parameter?

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, robotframework

The web page has a table with 11 check boxes.

I want to have the flexibility to let tester just input 1 or 2 or 3 to select specific checkbox.

How do I build the keyword with just `ONE variable`? so the tester do not need to input many lines of element variable.

the elements:

```
xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[1]
xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[2]
xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[3]
```

current script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser

*** Variables ***
${Checkbox-1}   xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[1]
${Checkbox-2}   xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[2]
${Checkbox-2}   xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[3]

*** Test Cases ***
   Click    ${Checkbox-1}
   Click    ${Checkbox-2}
   Click    ${Checkbox-3}
```

expect script:

```
    *** Settings ***
    Library    Browser
    
    *** Variables ***
    ${Checkbox-1}   xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[1]
    ${Checkbox-2}   xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[2]
    ${Checkbox-2}   xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[3]
    ${CustomCheckbox}   I don't know how to construct
    *** Test Cases ***
    User select checkbox 1 and 2
      [Arguments]    ${not sure}  
       Click    ${CustomCheckbox}   1     2
```

outer html of first row in table

```
<tr data-row-key="1" class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0">
    <td class="ant-table-cell ant-table-selection-column">
        <label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper">
            <span class="ant-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value="">
                    <span class="ant-checkbox-inner"/>
                </span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="ant-table-cell">1</td>
        <td class="ant-table-cell">101-39s5mb.mp4</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword implements below.

```
*** Variables ***
${checkbox_xpath}    xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Log To Console    \nClick 1
    Name That You Want    1
    Log To Console    Click 2 and 3
    Name That You Want    2    3

*** Keywords ***
Name That You Want
    [Arguments]    @{index}
    
    FOR    ${key}    IN    @{index}
        Log To Console    ${checkbox_xpath}\[${key}\]
    END
```

Output:

```
==============================================================================
Main
==============================================================================
Test
Click 1
.xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[1]
.Click 2 and 3
.xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[2]
xpath=(//input[@class="ant-checkbox-input"])[3]
Test                                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Main                                                                  | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: actually I expect to add argument at test cases so I can feed which check box [1] or [2] to tick....is your solution about the same? I am not sure what is Test1    Test2    Test3

Comment: i add 'expect script:' at main post, I suppose something like that but not sure what to do.

Comment: @user12158726 Okay, I just know what you want. I edit my answer. You can check it again.

Comment: Yes your latest solution closer. Just that if i have 100 checkbixes then i need to key in 100 lines at ***variables***

Comment: @user12158726 If you can make sure the XPath is consistent besides the number in the parentheses. You will not key the variables 100 times in code.

Comment: yes, that is my original question, how do I make the variable just one? the design is consistent that just append 1,2,3,4,5 at each row.

Comment: @user12158726 I think your problem needed to be described more precisely in the original post.  I edit my answer that only uses one variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Evaluate** function to do this.

```
*** Settings ***

Library    Browser
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${Checkbox}   xpath=(//input[@class='ant-checkbox-input'])[{0}]

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Click Checkbox    1  3  9

*** Keywords ***
Click Checkbox 
    [Arguments]  @{Values}
    FOR     ${value}    IN    @{Values}
        ${final xpath}    Evaluate    "${Checkbox}".format("${value}")
        Click Element    ${final xpath}
    END
```

## Final xpath will have the below output based on the values that you have provided

(//input[@class='ant-checkbox-input'])[1],
(//input[@class='ant-checkbox-input'])[3]....(//input[@class='ant-checkbox-input'])[9]

Or You can use below method

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${Checkbox}   xpath=//input[@class='ant-checkbox-input']

*** Test Cases ***

Click Checkbox 

*** Keywords ***

Click Checkbox 
     # If you dont know how many elements it has,then you can get all the elements and click one by one.
     ${list of elements}  Get Webelements  ${Checkbox}
     For    ${element}   in  ${list of elements}
        Click Element    ${element}
```

Comment: i think your solution will check all the checkbox? how do I pass argument to specifically tick checkbox 1, checkbox 3?

Comment: i add 'expect script:' at main post, I suppose something like that but not sure what to do.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your expectation, Please check it again. you don't need to create multiple variables just need to pass the argument to single variable